# issue with hireracally clearing a directory in linux

Tags: linux

hi i have a requirement like the following

`|
|------bar/
    |--file.pl
    |---FILE1.FILE2.FILE3.TXT
    |---FILE4.FILE5.FILE6.TXT
    |
    |---subdir1/
    |   |---file1_file2.log
    |   |---file2_file1.log
    |
    |---subdir2/
        |---image1_image2.log
        |---image2_image1.log`

i am using the following command.

find bar -type f -name "*.txt" -o -name "*.log" -o -name "*.csv" -print0 |
xargs -0 rm -f

and the output i am getting is as follows

`|
|------bar/
    |--file.pl
    |---FILE1.FILE2.FILE3.TXT
    |---FILE4.FILE5.FILE6.TXT
    |
    |---subdir1/
    |   |---file1_file2.log
    |   |---file2_file1.log
    |
    |---subdir2/
        |---image1_image2.log
        |---image2_image1.log`

but i want the output like the following.

`|
|------bar/
    |
    |--file.pl
    |
    |
    |---subdir1/
    |

    |

    |
    |---subdir2/`

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this method also

```
find  bar/ -type f -iname "*[^.pl]" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```